# Phonegap navigator.contacts.find does not work

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've installed a contacts plugin for phonegap:

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts
```

Then wrote a class:

```
function ContactList () {
  var _this = this;

  function _onSuccess(contacts) {
    alert('success fired');
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
    }
  }

  function _onError(contactError) {
    alert('error fired');
  }

  this.get = function(callback) {
    alert('contacts get started');
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";         
    options.multiple = true;      
    var filter = ["displayName", "name"]; 

    alert('starting navigator.contacts.find'); // << This guy is the last one

    navigator.contacts.find(filter, _onSuccess, _onError, options);

  }
}
```

And when I call get method:

```
  var contactList = new ContactList();
  contactList.get();
```

The last message I get is "starting navigator.contacts.find" which means that both onSuccess and onError are never called. Hence navigator.contacts.find does not work.

Do you have any solutions for it?

P.S. tried to reinstall the plugin a couple of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using cordova except of phonegap